# SES url's with Railo/tomcat that have dynamic subfolders

Tags: tomcat, railo

I've had success getting SES urls to work such as `http://mydomain.com/index.cfm/foo/bar` using `<url-pattern>/index.cfm/*</url-pattern>`, however this only works for the root and if the folders are known. If for example i have a sub folder with a child application that employs the same trick `http://mydomain.com/products/index.cfm/foo/bar` i can also get it to work by using `<url-pattern>/products/index.cfm/*</url-pattern>`, however, if there are folders between `/products/` and `index.cfm/foo/bar` with dynamic names i would have to make a url pattern for each name because `<url-pattern>/products/*/index.cfm/*</url-pattern>` won't work.

Any ideas other than re-building the application to not use a dynamic folder structure or having to populate this web.xml dynamically each time a folder is added/removed/changed?

Comment: Note: if doing this is a bad idea or isn't possible, point that out too. That would be good grounds to move in the direction of a re-write.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can run Railo on Jetty instead which has more sophisticated URL pattern support I believe (since this is a Tomcat restriction, not a Railo issue per se).

Comment: Unfortunately Jetty has the same restriction of only one wildcard in url-pattern, _however_ it allows you to workaround this by having url rewriting built-in combined with the ability to get the original requested path with Railo/CFML afterwards. (I'll provide more info on doing that in a bit.)

Comment: Moving to Jetty is an option, however if it came to that we would rather re-build the structure since it needs to be re-built anyway. We just wanted to make sure we weren't missing something with tomcat's url-pattern.