# What would cause a tomcat 404 with Railo 4 and mod_cfml for SES urls like /index.cfm/event/main.home?

Tags: apache, tomcat, railo, cfml

I'm getting:

```
HTTP Status 404 - /admin/index.cfm/event/main.welcome

type Status report

message /admin/index.cfm/event/main.welcome

description The requested resource is not available.
Apache Tomcat/7.0.37
```

But it works fine when I go to:

```
/admin/index.cfm?event=main.welcome
```

OR

```
/admin/event/main.welcome (thanks to htaccess)
```

But since this is using MOD_CFML I can't use HTACCESS to override url's that have .cfm in them.

I can't find this anywhere on the web... :-/

Comment: You have to add /admin/index.cfm/* to the ses url mappings in tomcat, unless someone knows of a more universal way to make these work. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12204536/ses-urls-with-railo-tomcat-that-have-dynamic-subfolders

Comment: Ya, this works great... but definitely not IDEAL for multiple projects of course...  If you add this as a solution answer I will approve it.  It does SOLVE the problem but I would love it if there was a "MOD_CFML" or Apache solution that could make it more flexible for storing these rewrites in the codebase per project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add this to your `web.xml` under the *"Basic SES Mappings"*:

```
<url-pattern>/admin/index.cfm/*</url-pattern>
```

As far as I know, there's no way to set it up to handle dynamic sub folders, you'd have to add one of these for each sub folder that you have pages like this in.

Comment: Thank you, this worked.  Maybe someday there will be a more prominent solution across the board but for now this will do just fine.

Comment: Kevin, you rock... You just end my frustration.